# Export extJS Panel content into PDF using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, extjs, extjs4, jspdf

I am trying to export ExtJS panel content into a PDF format. The panel contains few ExtJS and HTML components which get added dynamically.

```
me.outputFramePanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    region: 'center',
    autoScroll: true,
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch ',
        pack: 'center'
    },
    style: 'margin:10px 20px 10px 20px;'
});
```

The data has been added to the panel in the following way.

```
    for (var i=0;i<imgsArr.length;i++){ 
        var image = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
            src: imgsArr[i].src,
            width: 750,
            height: 500
        });
    }

me.outputFramePanel.insert(me.itemIndex, image);
me.itemIndex+=me.itemIndex;
```

What I am trying to do is, onClick of an Export button, the Ext panel data should get exported in PDF format.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function(element, renderer){
        return true;
    }
};
doc.fromHTML($('#render_me').get(0), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170, 
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
```

https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

But instead of $('#render_me').get(0) i want to put me.outputFramePanel and should be able to export data in PDF format.

Please help!

Also, does jsPDF support Japanese characters?

Thanks and regards,
Stu

Comment: Any alternatives for jsPDF ?

Comment: Try replacing the `$('#render_me').get(0)` with `me.outputFramePanel.el.dom`.

Comment: It is executing but the PDF is coming as empty with nothing in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of effort found this. In order to make it work, You need to put the code in HTML iframe and make it available as a wholesome. 
Meaning you cannot dynamically create HTML body and add your components to it. Create your components in a separate Javascript file and add to the HTML created.
Use double-quotes when creating html something like below - It won't work with single quotes and adding elements here will also fail resulting in no errors and no output.

```
var innerHtml = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>" +
        "<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'/><title>Report</title>"+
        "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>" +
        "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='./../scripts/external/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css'/>"+
        "<script type='text/javascript' src='./../scripts/external/extjs/js/ext-all.js'></script>"+
        "<script type='text/javascript' src='./../scripts/external/jquery.min.1.9.1.js'></script>"+
        "<script type='text/javascript' src='./../scripts/app/view/myjavascriptComponentsfile.js'></script>"+
        "</head><body></body></html>";
```

Now add it to your Ext Panel as iFrames srcdoc.

```
me.outputFramePanel.add({
    width: me.framePanelWidth,
    bodyStyle : 'overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto',
    style: 'border:1px solid #b7bcc4;',
    height:"100%",
    html: '<iframe id="frameReportPanel" name="frameReportPanelName" align="middle" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 name="frame"'+
          ' width="'+ me.framePanelWidth + '" height="'+ me.framePanelHeight +'" srcdoc="'+ innerHtml +'"></iframe>'
});
```

Now call document.getElementById('frameReportPanel') and do the jsPDF print on it.

And no, it doesn't support Japanese character set.

FYI, I didn't use iFrame or jsPDF in my application, it's a good tool but I required language support, instead I went for printElement -> http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/

I hope it's helpful. :)